# search directory and ignore hidden files iOS

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I'd like to get the content of a directory excluding the hidden files.I get the contents of a directory using

```
-[NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: error:];
```

And I want to filter it with `NSPredicate`.The problem is I'm blind about the predicate format.

Could anyone help me?
Or Thanks If you can provide another method to implement it.